# Distance matrices and their determinants

Tags: graph-theory

What are the usages of distance matrices in graph theory? What information do their determinants provide?
I know that determinant is 0 if graph contains cycle of even length, and I also know about Graham-Pollak theorem, and the formula for complete graphs, but what else is there?

Also, what are applications of distance matrices in other sciences, and what other ways to define distance are used?